# fancy style of chapter heading

Tags: memoir, chapters

I want to write chapter title as attached. For that this code doesn't work for me. Any suggestion:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\setSingleSpace{1.1}
\SingleSpacing
\usepackage{xcolor,calc, blindtext}
\definecolor{chaptercolor}{gray}{0.8}
% helper macros
\newcommand\numlifter[1]{\raisebox{-2cm}[0pt][0pt]{\smash{#1}}}
\newcommand\numindent{\kern37pt}
\newlength\chaptertitleboxheight
\makechapterstyle{hansen}{
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand\printchapternum{%
    \begingroup%
    \leavevmode%
    \chapnumfont%
    \strut%
    \numlifter{\thechapter}%
    \numindent%
\endgroup%
}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{%
    \vphantom{\begingroup%
      \leavevmode%
      \chapnumfont%
      \numlifter{\vphantom{9}}%
      \numindent%
      \endgroup}
    \afterchapternum}
  \setlength\midchapskip{0pt}
  \setlength\beforechapskip{0.5\baselineskip}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{3\baselineskip}
  \renewcommand\chapnumfont{%
    \fontsize{4cm}{0cm}%
    \bfseries%
    \sffamily%
    \color{chaptercolor}%
  }
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{%
    \normalfont%
    \huge%
    \bfseries%
    \raggedleft%
  }%
  \settototalheight\chaptertitleboxheight{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{\chaptitlefont \strut bg\\bg\strut}}
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
    \parbox[t][\chaptertitleboxheight][t]{\textwidth}{%
      %\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}% add this if you use microtype
      \chaptitlefont\strut ##1\strut}%
}}
\chapterstyle{hansen}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty} % just to save some space
\begin{document}
\chapter{Hansen Memoir Chapter Style}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly doesn't work for you (i.e. what errors or result do you get)?

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: File `kpfonts.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: iqra.tex
(./iqra.tex

! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 \documentclass{
                   memoir}
?

Comment: So you don't have the package "kpfonts" installed. Perhaps download and install it? (I know it's part of the TeXlive distribution, so it should be available on CTAN). With that package installed, your code works for me with PdfLatex, XeLatex and LuaLatex.

Comment: by adding only \usepackage{kpfonts} will not work?

Comment: In MikTeX (Windows), if you request a package that is not installed, then the program will attempt to download and install it. In texlive (Windows, Linux, Mac), if you request a package that is not installed, then the program does NOT attempt to get it for you; instead, an error results.