# Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjarne doesn't work for me

Tags: pdftex, templates

Attached figure is my preamble. Any one could please suggest me that why **Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjarne** doesn't work for me?

```
\documentclass[paper=letter, fontsize=12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
%Options: Sonny, Lenny, Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjarne, Bjornstrup

\textwidth=450pt\oddsidemargin=0pt

%\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}
```

Comment: You're a member of TeX.SE and post a screen shot of code?

Comment: Most likely explanation: Glenn, Conny, Rejne, and Bjarne are members of the International Brotherhood of TeX Workers. They are on strike. That is why they are not working. Now, if that explanation does not satisfy you, then please post ordinary text (compilable) instead of a screen shot.

Comment: it is now edited.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Note that what you are doing with `\textwidth` and `\oddsidemargin` is simply wrong. You load the `geometry` package. Use it to adjust your page layout.

Comment: Aren't you the same guy that posted [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424999/fancy-style-of-chapter-heading) about a chapter style with another document class (memoir) about 1h ago?

Comment: @remco: Apparently he/she is ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the package documentation:

> In the release (1.1) of the current package. A modification was made such that it will work with the
>   book class. The problem occurred when the `fncychap` styles *Conny, Rejne, Bjarne or Glenn* were used
>   in conjunction with the LATEX command
>   `\tabelofcontents`. The exact reason for the error is not yet found. The problem was reported by Olivier Guibe.

As pointed out by @Skillmon in the comments, it looks like this package is broken again, or has some bug interacting with other packages you are using. Looking at the date of the last update, I would not expect it to be fixed any time soon.

Comment: I have version 1.34 installed and they are not working for me, too, if I use a `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: This isn't an answer as it doesn't solve the issue (which I guess is not your fault, since the documentation makes a false claim in not solving the issue with that update). With the latest version installed try the following document: `\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}`

Comment: @Skillmon You are right, I didn't check before answering. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks my friends all of them are worked for me now.

Comment: @Higgs how? Without using a `\tableofcontents` or what? Is that really an option?

Comment: I just removed \textwidth=450pt\oddsidemargin=0pt which someone commented and then he edited his comment which can't see anymore.

Comment: @Skillmon, Yes without using \tableofcontents

Comment: @Higgs the comment is written by me and still viewable under your question. Read the `geometry` documentation to see how you can customize the page layout with it. Not using `\tableofcontents` doesn't seem like a solution to me. Not using this package and building your own chapter headlines seems like the way to go for me.